# Adding URLs to sublime text 3 menu item doesn't work if file path has spaces in it. How do you escape text in for ST3?

Tags: sublimetext3, customization, sublimetext

I don't know how to express this in a succinct way, so here is the convoluted way.  Clearly, I am playing around with and trying to customize Sublime Text 3. I thought I should get that out of the way, as quickly as possible. ;)

Anyway, I ran across an example that allows you to add a menu item to the ST3 menu list that is in essence a URL.  I added it to the Help menu.

Code snippet:

```
  {
    "caption": "Help",
    "mnemonic": "H",
    "id": "help",
    "children": [
      {
        "command": "open_url",
        "caption": "Twitter",
        "args": {"url": "https://twitter.com/WhatsTrending"}
      },
    ],
  },
```

Then, I thought, wouldn't it be cool if it could also open some local file, so then I added this:

```
  { 
    "caption" : "Local File",
    "command" : "open_url",
      "args" : { "url": "file:///Users/<username>/me.html" },
  },
```

And to my surprise it worked! It opened the local file in the browser, so I got excited, and thought that since the place to save any customization for ST3 is `"~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User"` I thought I would save the local html file there. So now I've added this:

```
  {
    "caption":"ST3 Custom File",
    "command" : "open_url",
      "args": {"url": "file:///Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/me.html"}
     },
  },
```

I was expecting to work, but it didn't so I am quite baffled. My guess is that the spaces in the path need to be escaped but everything I'm trying is failing, does anyone know how to properly escape this?

Clearly, doing this doesn't work `"file:///Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/User/me.html"` as the string is not evaluated or interpolated.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, 30 minutes after posting I tried something that ended up working.  Since I couldn't think of anything else I tried URL encoding and that actually ended up working. All I had to do was replace " " (space) with "%20" and viola! It works as expected.

So that last one, now looks like this:

```
  {
    "caption":"ST3 Custom File",
    "command" : "open_url",
      "args": {"url": "file:///Users/<username>/Library/Application%20Support/Sublime%20Text%203/Packages/User/me.html"}
   },
```

And it ST3 does open the html file in the default browser.  Anyway, I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did the method from the other answer (\ ) work as well?

Comment: @Cerberus I tried to escape using the "\ " method as described by the last lines of my question.  I think the reason for that, is that the JSON flavor used for ST3 settings doesn't allow for the strings to mutate, so there can't be any interpolation or escaping.